# asyncio: run one function threaded with multiple requests from websocket clients

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a websocket server *(python 3.x)* taking requests where each is a url variable. It runs just fine except it only executes each request in serial, after one another. *While the function is running it also blocks the client(s) trying to connect.* Non-blocking is what i want!

- Asyncronous <del>multiprocessed</del> threading of both websocket and subprocess function.
- <del>The ability to set the number of cores to use. This is not obligatory though.</del>

<del>Here's what i've got:</del>

---

### ANSWER (illustration and `asyncio.subprocess` in accepted answer)

So, I didn't get very far with this frustration. I reverted back to my original code and as it turns out, you need to sleep the function with `await asyncio.sleep(.001)`. Now it runs perfectly fine, I tested with multiple clients at the same time and it handles it asynchronously.

```
import asyncio, websockets, json
async def handler(websocket, path):
    print("New client connected.")
    await websocket.send('CONNECTED')
    try:
        while True:
            inbound = await websocket.recv()
            if inbound is None:
                break
            while inbound != None:
                import time
                for line in range(10):
                    time.sleep(1)
                    data = {}
                    data['blah'] = line
                    await asyncio.sleep(.000001) # THIS
                    print(data)
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))
                await websocket.send(json.dumps({'progress': 'DONE'}))
                break
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        print("Client disconnected.")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = websockets.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', 8080)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()
```

**Update:** as suggested by **@udi**, if you want a slow external process, the way to go is asyncio.subprocess and not subprocess. Reading from pipe with a blocking call stalls the other threads, which is what asyncio.subprocess takes care of.

Comment: I don't know enough about `asyncio` to be able to put together a working example, but I think you want to be using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to handle your blocking jobs. The `asyncio` event loop has a method `run_in_executor`, which you can pass a task and a executor, which is probably what you want to do in your `ws` coroutine instead of directly yielding from `download`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i didn't get it to work. As it turns out, i went back to my original code, did a little edit and now it works asynchronous. Although I cant figure out how to set the number of cores, i'm fine with this. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time.sleep()` is blocking.

Try:

```
# blocking_server.py
import asyncio
import time

import websockets

x = 0


async def handler(websocket, path):
    global x
    x += 1
    client_id = x

    try:
        print("[#{}] Connected.".format(client_id))

        n = int(await websocket.recv())
        print("[#{}] Got: {}".format(client_id, n))
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            print("[#{}] zzz...".format(client_id))
            time.sleep(1)
            print("[#{}] woke up!".format(client_id))
            await asyncio.sleep(.001)
            msg = "*" * i
            print("[#{}] sending: {}".format(client_id, msg))
            await websocket.send(msg)

        msg = "bye!"
        print("[#{}] sending: {}".format(client_id, msg))
        await websocket.send(msg)

        print("[#{}] Done.".format(client_id, msg))

    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        print("[#{}] Disconnected!.".format(client_id))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = 8080
    server = websockets.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', port)
    print("Started server on port {}".format(port))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()
```

With this test client:

```
# test_client.py
import asyncio
import time

import websockets


async def client(client_id, n):
    t0 = time.time()
    async with websockets.connect('ws://localhost:8080') as websocket:
        print("[#{}] > {}".format(client_id, n))
        await websocket.send(str(n))
        while True:
            resp = await websocket.recv()
            print("[#{}] < {}".format(client_id, resp))
            if resp == "bye!":
                break

    print("[#{}] Done in {:.2f} seconds".format(client_id, time.time() - t0))


tasks = [client(i + 1, 3) for i in range(4)]
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()
```

Now compare the result when `time.sleep(x)` is replaced with `await asyncio.sleep(x)`!

If you need to run a slow external process via asyncio, try [`asynico.subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html):

An example external program:

```
# I am `slow_writer.py`
import sys
import time

n = int(sys.argv[1])

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("*" * i)
```

with this server:

```
# nonblocking_server.py

import asyncio
import sys

import websockets

x = 0


async def handler(websocket, path):
    global x
    x += 1
    client_id = x

    try:
        print("[#{}] Connected.".format(client_id))

        n = int(await websocket.recv())

        print("[#{}] Got: {}. Running subprocess..".format(client_id, n))

        cmd = (sys.executable, 'slow_writer.py', str(n))
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            *cmd, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

        async for data in proc.stdout:
            print("[#{}] got from subprocess, sending: {}".format(
                client_id, data))
            await websocket.send(data.decode().strip())

        return_value = await proc.wait()
        print("[#{}] Subprocess done.".format(client_id))

        msg = "bye!"
        print("[#{}] sending: {}".format(client_id, msg))
        await websocket.send(msg)

        print("[#{}] Done.".format(client_id, msg))

    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        print("[#{}] Disconnected!.".format(client_id))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    port = 8080
    server = websockets.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', port)
    print("Started server on port {}".format(port))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Yes, this is a great example. I was not using `sleep()` from either `time` nor `asyncio`. `asyncio.subprocess` looks interesting, but I need `universal_newline` which `asyncio.subprocess` doesn't support. It seems to be no noticeable difference using `subprocess` instead. I have no explanation for this though. I guess `asyncio.sleep()` allows the waiting thread to pass GIL?

Comment: `asyncio.sleep` schedules the task to for future execution; Meanwhile other tasks can take control.

Comment: `async for data in proc.stdout: text = data.decode()` should convert your data to str instead of `universal_newlines`.

Comment: Oh, so by doing that other tasks utilize GIL?
Yeah, I did `data.decode()` with no luck in parsing a progress bar in the output, but with a `split('\r')` in `for` loop it was no problem. Great, much better! I read up on `asyncio.subprocess` and it seems to be the way to go with asyncio. Thank you.